# Count button not showing count when not logged in to Facebook

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

Something very strange has happened to my like button in my site (http:// nadlantest dot co dot il)

After count reached 100 it stopped showing the count when you load the page while not logged into facebook... i.e. no facebook session cookie..

I'm sure that it did work beforehand...

Comment: Guys, this has been sitting here for a long while already without any posts....anyone ? It is clear to me that I'm missing something which is probably obvious to others...

Comment: you know what, let me place it differently, I am sure that many of you have experienced this weird behaviour when integrated like button in your site...what was the solution you've found ?

Comment: I'm trying to find an answer for the same problem.